# Perf difference between Transactional read-only READS vs READS outside of a spring transaction

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

In spring boot, as I understand, by default, all repository methods run within a spring transaction since the `SimpleJpaRepository` has the annotation `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` at the class level and all the write methods have the method level annotation `@Transactional`.

My question is, wrt the DB load / performance wise, which option is better for query methods (i.e) The ones that don't write to DB.

1. The default way, where a read only transaction is present.
2. Disabling the default spring transactions with `@EnableJpaRepositories(enableDefaultTransactions = false)` and enabling transactions only for WRITE methods, so that no explicit transaction will be initiated for READ methods.

has any experiments been done to understand the pref difference between these 2 ways?

Both the options work fine when tried locally. So this question is to understand which option is better perf / DB load wise.